# What’s wrong with my local Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a Rails application I started a full year ago. It’s a Rails 2.3 app.

Now, someone else has made remote changes (it’s on Github, sorry, but it’s private).  And I have done

```
sudo gem update
```

that is, updated all my gems, including Rails (to 3).

Realizing this, I have done

```
rake:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.3.8
```

or whatever to make this release use that version of rails, hoping this was the solution.

however, no such luck so far.

I get errors trying to start the server, AND trying to run `script/console` (though it’s *more* successful).

**Note that *this exact application* works just fine on EngineYard.**

**Server:**

```
 $ script/server
 => Booting Mongrel
 => Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load': syntax error on line 45, col 3: `' (ArgumentError)
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:902:in `database_configuration'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:437:in `initialize_database'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/config/environment.rb:11
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
  from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from script/server:3
```

**Console:**

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load':ArgumentError: syntax error on line 45, col 3:`rai'

And when, in console, I try to use a defined model:

> > @mm = MyModel.find(:all)
> >      NameError: uninitialized constant MyModel
> >       from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
> >       from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in`const_missing'
> >       from /Users/ajh/Sites/PROJECT_NAME/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
> >       from (irb):1

Comment: Can you post your full database.yml file?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like something is going on in your yaml.rb. Can you require it in irb and load a simple YAML file?

Comment: Thanks, Garrett; I found a stray `end` keyword and a bit of other fishiness in my database.yml. Removing it did the trick. Thanks so much, both of you, and everyone who took a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `database.yml` had a stray `end` keyword. Cleaning up that file solved my problems. Thanks to Garrett for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6):

I just had this error, and the problem turned out to be that I'd used a tab instead of a double-space in the database.yml file. Thought I'd mention it, in case others have the same trouble.